# .NET Core Dependencies and Frameworks Understanding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have been working on .NET Core from a few weeks now. At first it was a great overhaul from Microsoft to the old .NET way of doing things. But now its getting on my nerves. Below is my original `global.json`:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1",
  }
}
```

This is my `project.json`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-*"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

And here is my `hosting.json`:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot"
}
```

I have created an Empty ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web Application Project, all I am trying to do is create an AngularJs application. But I cannot access the `wwwroot` directory since I am not able to:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

I removed the `dnx451` from my original `project.json` and also changed the `global.json` to:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1",
    "runtime": "coreclr",
    "architecture": "x64"
  }
}
```

*Error:*
`Error NU1002 The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 1.0.0-rc2-20248 in project QMS.UI does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0. QMS.UI ..\QMS.UI\src\QMS.UI\project.json`

I have read a lot of blogs and stackoverflow answers. Can anybody tell me in very high level way how does we:

- Effectively find a valid package, that will suite our target framework.
- Effectively make all frameworks (if listed in the project.json) happy with that dependency notation? (Sometimes I get an error, its available for `dnx451` but not `dnxcore50`) (Should I use the #if dnxcore50... etc notations?)

Please help! I am going through a similar trouble in another project based on .NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static file dependency is form RC2 and is not compatible with RC1 you use in rest of your project.

Either you use all packages from RC1 or all from RC2, but be aware that RC2 dependencies often break (one package requires version xyz, where other package is not yet updated and requires old library but due to API changes can't work with the newer version).

This are RC1 packages

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
```

This are RC2 packages (you can recognize them on their name, `Microsoft.AspNet.*` packages got renamed to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` some time during RC2 cycle

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
"Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-*"
```

> - Effectively find a valid package, that will suite our target framework.

First step is to target only the same versions. If you need a stable environment use RC1 until RC2 is released. However, be aware that there are quite a few breaking changes. Check out the [ASP.NET Core GitHub annoucements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/milestones/1.0.0-rc2) (mostly breaking changes) for more information.

> - Effectively make all frameworks (if listed in the project.json) happy with that dependency notation? (Sometimes I get an error, its available for dnx451 but not dnxcore50) (Should I use the #if dnxcore50... etc notations?)

Depends on the assemblies you need. Some have compatible api with both target platforms, but most don't. Usually that's how you would switch out platform dependent assemblies/code.

Be aware that there is a difference if you use a Class Library (Package) or .NET Core application (Webproject, unit test project).

For RC1, the monikers are `dnx451` (or `dnx452`, `dnx46`) for full .NET Framework targeting and `dnxcore50` for .NET Core. For Class Libraries however, you have to use `net451` (or `net452`/`net46`) for full .NET Framework target and `dotnet5.x` (x=1-4, i RC2 also 5) for .NET Core.

Comment: I updated the `IIS` and `Kestrel` to the following: `"1.0.0-*"`
the packages were successfully restored and it brought with it the RC2 packages. The old problem didnt get solved, but rather another error has been added to the list:
`Error CS0103 The name 'WebApplication' does not exist in the current context QMS.UI.DNX Core 5.0 ...\QMS.UI\src\QMS.UI\Startup.cs`

Comment: I did the following changes to the project.json:

`{"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*"` `"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*"` `"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*"  }`

Now those old errors has gone. But `Startup.cs` is reporting `WebApplication.Run` does not exists.

Comment: Also I saw that it is still using all RC2 packages as per References Tree in Solution Explorer. Strange! :S

Comment: You are still using outdated packages. As I posted above, the new ones for RC2 are named `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*`, not `Microsoft.AspNet.*`. See the announcement https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144. Some of the older RC2 packages still use the old names, but the newer one use new, but since they also have breaking changes you need the latest ones and hope to be lucky that the ci feed is updated :) Also MVC6 on dnx needs an additional package to run, see this announcement https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/154

Comment: If you want to work with RC2 it's best to fix your version numbers (once oyu found a working setup) rather than use `1.0.0-*`, as next day you restart visual studio (and it does a package restore), your dependencies may break again

Comment: Yes I understood your point and renamed all to use `AspNetCore` but this isn't working with my DNX. And it starts throwing 54 errors. When I renamed it to `AspNet` it builds the solution successfully and shows `1.0.0-rc2-XXX` against all the loaded assemblies. I know its against what you are saying, but that's happening. What should I do? This is my DNVM LIST:

- 1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64

- 1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86

- * 1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64

- 1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86

Comment: Trying your last advice. Which is to find the version numbers that works best.

Comment: cannot get it to work. Now the application is building up without errors but cannot make the WebApp to run. Tried: [WebApplication renamed to WebHost](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/141)... Also tried this: [MusicStoreExample](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/src/MusicStore/Program.cs#L5-L17) But nothing seems to run in the Main Function in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: You also need rc2 runtime. dnvm upgrade -u latest should work, but as I said, frequent updates to either assemblies or runtime can easily break stuff. So unless you are making a open source library or so its probably not worth the trouble to get broken dependencies all the time

Comment: Any reason you can't work with rc1 until rc2 is released?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106660/discussion-between-freshdev-and-tseng).

Comment: Problems got resolved after setting each package's version to:
"1.0.0-rc1-final" :) Thanks a lot Tseng! **_very important pieces of advice for everybody out there is mentioned by him, this will definitely help the other newbie to .NET Core like me!_**